# Laravel 9 Rate Limiter для заданий (jobs)

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Столкнулся с проблемой задания лимитов для `Job` в `Laravel 9`.

Хочу задать лимиты для заданий, с учетом пользователей.

Делаю так как в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#job-middleware) написано.

Первый шаг.
В провайдере задаю поминутный лимит для каждого пользователя (Задаю `id` пользователя как ключ)

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->register(RepositoryServiceProvider::class);
        $this->app->register(RequestValidationProvider::class);
        $this->app->register(CustomServiceProvider::class);
    }

    public function boot(): void
    {
        RateLimiter::for('Limiter', function (object $job) {
            Log::info($job->userId);
            return Limit::perMinute(10)->by($job->userId)->response(function() {
                Log::info('Too many attempts!');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Следующий шаг добавить в само задание метод `middleware` с тем именем `RateLimiter`-а который мы создали в `AppServiceProvider`.

Вот сам код задания.

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Services\Crm\ServiceFactory;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\Middleware\RateLimitedWithRedis;

class SendEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(
        private readonly string $crmSlug,
        private readonly array $email,
        public readonly int $userId
    ){}
    public function handle(ServiceFactory $serviceFactory): void
    {
        $service = $serviceFactory->get($this->slug);

        $service->sendEmail($this->email);
    }

    public function middleware(): array
    {
        Log::info(json_encode(new RateLimitedWithRedis('Limiter')));
        return [new RateLimitedWithRedis('Limiter')];
    }
}
```

И вот сейчас когда запустить задание, `Laravel` всегда должен смотреть в эту минуту сколько заданий уже сделано. Превышен лимит или нет. Тоесть запусить следующее задание или нет.

По сути из провайдера к заданию, перед его выполнением должен идти `true / false`. Выполнить или подождать.

Вот что в логе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И у меня всегда идет `true`. И лимит не срабатывает.

Вот сама документация [Laravel Job Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#job-middleware).

Это `config/queue.php`
И в `.env` `QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто столкнулся с такой проблемой? Можете подсказать что делаю не правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По сути все что написано, было верно.

Но есть один важный нюанс.

Когда задания поподают в очередь. И те которые не проходит `middleware`. Их попытки увеличиваются (`tries`). Тоесть если например в вашем задании написано.

```
public $tries = 2;
```

И это задание 2 раза не пройдет `middleware`. То уже вы его потеряли. Его надо будет запустить еще раз.

Для этого можно использовать метод `failed` для задания. И там все это реализовать.

Вот пример.

```
public function failed(MaxAttemptsExceededException $exception): void
{
    $errorCode = $exception->getCode();
    if($errorCode === 0 || $errorCode > 400) {
        $this->job->release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что ты верно настроил `RateLimiter`, но у тебя возможно неправильно настроен `middleware` для `Job`.

Попробуй изменить метод `middleware()` в `SendEmailJob` на следующее:

```
public function middleware(): array
{
    return [
        new RateLimitedWithRedis('Limiter')->timeout(1)->block(0)->releaseAfter(60)
    ];
}
```

Обрати внимание на вызов методов `timeout()`, `block()` и `releaseAfter()`. Они устанавливают время ожидания между попытками выполнения задачи, определяют поведение при блокировке задачи (`block(0)`) означает немедленное блокирование), и задают время, после которого блокировка будет снята (в данном случае, через 60 секунд).

Надеюсь, это поможет!

Comment: `RateLimitedWithRedis` нету метода `timeout()`   .
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Queue\Middleware\RateLimitedWithRedis::timeout()`